# Adding and styling border to a button or label in B4A (basic4android) with script?

Tags: styles, border, basic4android

I'm new to B4A. I want to add border to a button and change it's color with writing script in activity module, in B4A. What should I do? Tnx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a ColorDrawable and assign it to the button

`Dim cd As ColorDrawable
cd.Initialize(Colors.Green, 5dip)
Btn.background = cd`

Comment: I used initialize2(BackgroundColor,BorderRadius,BorderWidth,BorderColor). Your answer was very helpful... thanks a lot.